# start activity B from service, and main activity Aalways be called first

Tags: android, android-service

I have a launcher activity called MainActivity.

MainActivity will start KeyGuardService, and KeyGuardService regist a ScreenOFF receiver, and then in onReceive will start LockScreenActivity use startActivity.

But everytime, MainActivity will be showed before LockScreenActivity. I have tried many solutions according to other Qustions-issue.

Menifest is as fllow:

```
       <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example.mylockscreen.main"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".services.KeyGuardService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LockScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example.mylockscreen.lock"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

onReceive as follows

```
    BroadcastReceiver mMasterResetReciever = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, Constants.TAG + "service receive " + action);
        if ((action.equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"))
                && (Preferences.getUserPrefBoolean(context, "app_on", true)))
        {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
            localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            KeyGuardService.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            Log.d(TAG, Constants.TAG + "service start activity");
        }
    }
};
```

can anyone tell me why, thanks.

Comment: You mean when you switch ON the screen everytime, then MainActivity starts before LockScreenActivity ?

Comment: yes, I can see screen flashes

Comment: I use log to track, and found that MainActivity's onResume is called

Comment: Can you post the onReceive() function of BroadCast receiver and its contents.

Comment: Just curious why are you including `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`? In the documentation it says `Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher` and `the default system does not include graphical task management, you should not use this flag unless you provide some way for a user to return back to the tasks you have launched.`

Comment: int the beginning, I didn't use the flag, and the issue already exists. then i add it according to some other question-issue